# Element is not getting deleted in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct node {  
  struct node *next; 
  int data;
} *head;
```

After inserting elements to linked list I am using this delete function to delete the elements of linked list but program gets stuck. I don't know where am making mistake. Please help me.

```
void delete(int num1) {
   struct node *del ,*prev_node;
   del = head;

   if(del == NULL) {
     printf("\n The list is empty,cant delete element");
   } else {
     while(del != NULL) {
       if(del->data == num1) {
         if(del == head) {
           head = del->next;
           free(del);                  
         } else {
           prev_node->next = del->next;                      
           free(del);                    
         }
       } else {
         prev_node = del;
         del = del->next;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the problem. I cant find an implementation one. I would also add that is good practice to nulify your pointers after freeing them.

Comment: cannot see it directly. please post the full program so we can compile&run it.

Comment: Each node does not have the duplicate values​​?

Comment: The real problem with this code is IMHO that there are too many variables that you need to keep updated, and too many special cases to take care of. Using a `struct node **pp` ("double pointer") could remove a lot of of this complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set del to NULL after freeing it, so it'll never leave the loop.

```
free(del);
del = NULL;
```

Comment: This is not the case since he is cheking next node and not the deleted one at the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't update the value of `del` after deleting the node to which it points, resulting in undefined behavior in the next iteration of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Version with pointer-to-pointer:

```
void delete2(int num1) {
   struct node **pp;

   if( !head ) {
     printf("\n The list is empty,cant delete element");
        return;
   }
   for (pp = &head; *pp; ) {
       if((*pp)->data != num1) {
           pp = &(*pp)->next;
         } 
       else {
         struct node *del = *pp;
         *pp = del->next;
         free(del);
         }
       }
    }
  }
```